# Dfp ads not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, ads, google-dfp

I have a number of ads being displayed on a site. Currently some ads show and others don't, but the ad scripts have all been setup in the same manner. Below is the head script and an example ad unit script. I am using mapping to set certain ads to display on desktop and other on mobile, which is working for the ads in question.

The issue itself seems to fluctuate, for example, the homepage displays x5 MPUs and x2 leaderboard ads. Out of these, 3 MUPs and both leaderboards display. The remaining MPUs don't do anything. On other pages, there are similar display responses. If I remove googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); some ads turn on and others that were displaying turn off...

I've not used Dfp before so not sure on the best approach for configuration. Any tips would be appreciated.

```js
  var googletag = window.googletag || {}; googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

  (function() {
     var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
     var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
         '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
     document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  })();
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {

    /* Ad unit leaderboard mapping – desktop only */
    var mapping1 = googletag.sizeMapping().
      addSize([769, 0], [728, 90]). // Laptop/Desktop (creative dsiplayed from 769 upwards)
      addSize([320, 0], [[300, 50]]). // mobile show nothing as no 300x50 creative
      build();

    /* Ad unit leaderboard mapping – tablet and desktop */
    var mapping2 = googletag.sizeMapping().
      addSize([769, 0], [728, 90]). // Laptop/Desktop show nothing as no 728x90 creative
      addSize([320, 0], [[300, 50]]). // Mobile and tablet (creative being displayed from 320 upwards)
      build();

    /* Create array */
    var gptAdSlots = [];

    /* OC Header Leaderboard - Global */
    gptAdSlots[0] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCHDR', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541428303372-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());
    gptAdSlots[1] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEW_BTN_Button_Ad_Mobile_Global_300x50', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541438785512-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping2).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Home - Latest News MPU */
    gptAdSlots[2] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCHPLNMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432416376-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Home - Video MPU */
    gptAdSlots[3] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCHPVIDMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432472828-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Home - lower leaderboard */
    gptAdSlots[4] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCHPLBD', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432071852-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());
    // gptAdSlots[5] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEW_BTN_Button_Ad_Mobile_Global_300x50', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541438785512-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping2).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Nav - Insights MPU */
    gptAdSlots[6] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNIMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433466979-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Ambassador - trending short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[7] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCAMBSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432354529-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* News - Featured articles MPU */
    gptAdSlots[8] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNEWSFAMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541428161405-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* News - bottom leaderboard */
    gptAdSlots[9] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNEWSLBD', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541428246275-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* News - detail list MPU */
    gptAdSlots[11] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNEWSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541428407319-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Videos - leaderboard */
    gptAdSlots[12] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCVIDEOLBD', [[728, 90], [300, 50]], 'div-gpt-ad-1541431980921-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping1).setCollapseEmptyDiv(true).addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Videos - Video detail list MPU */
    gptAdSlots[14] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCVFVMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433185129-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Videos - Featured Videos MPU */
    gptAdSlots[15] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCVDMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433123972-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Events - Trending short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[16] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCETSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433060761-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Nav - Topics MPU */
    gptAdSlots[17] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNTMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433523476-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Nav - Multimedia MPU */
    gptAdSlots[18] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCNMMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433657317-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Partners - Trending Short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[19] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCPARTSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433398379-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Podcasts - Trending Short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[20] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCPODTSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433238285-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Infographic - Trending Short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[21] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCITSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433294564-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Journal - Trending Short MPU */
    gptAdSlots[22] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCJTSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433344917-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Article - related MPU */
    gptAdSlots[23] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCADRAMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432289951-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Article - MPU one */
    gptAdSlots[24] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCADMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432146332-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Article - MPU two */
    gptAdSlots[25] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCADMPU2', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541432235724-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Category Landing - one MPU */
    gptAdSlots[26] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCCATTSMPU', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433717945-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Category Landing - two MPU */
    gptAdSlots[27] = googletag.defineSlot('/6853333/NEWOCSAMPU1', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1541433878473-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    /* Start ad fetching */
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();

  });
```

```html
<div class="advert-container-block">
  <div class="mpu">

    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1541428407319-0'>
      <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1541428407319-0'); });
      </script>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now fixed. For reference the issue was fixed with the following:

1. Removing googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
2. Removing duplicated IDs!!